# How to separate logic correctly into separate applications?

Tags: python, django, django-2.2

I implement simple django website, where I tried to separate different parts from website in different APPs, but I'm facing some problems:

I have two django apps, right now (core - where are heaader, footer, index) and (objects - where I have objects which I want to list at index page):

**core/templates/header.html** (header elements, login, logout etc)

**core/templates/index.html** (html tags, blocks, etc..):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    {% block 'head-title' %}
    {% endblock %}
    {% load static %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
      integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
      crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <script src="{% static 'core/js/custom.js' %}"></script>
</head>
<body>
    {% include 'header.html' %}
    {% block 'body' %}
    {% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

**core/templates/home.html** (homepage - here I want to list all Objects and implement filters for them):

```
{% extends 'index.html' %}

{% block 'body' %}
{% endblock %}
```

**core/views.py:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect


def show_home_page(request):
    return render(request, "home.html")
```

Ok everything is perfect, but now I don't know how to add listing of elements:

What I tried is to call Object model in `show_home_page()` function with `Object.objects.all()` and pass this list to `home.html` and for filters to call same function with parameters, for example def `show_home_page(request, price_up, distance):` But then I mess `objects` logic in `core` APP, which is not good I think. Variant 2 is to set this logic in `objects/views.py` but then I should return `home.html` from `objects` app which is not correct again, I think.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying to keep features (and layers) well decoupled is a laudable goal, but you still need to make everybody work together at some point... which means you *do* need some coupling somewhere.

The first obvious "integration layer" candidate is the templates - they are (mostly) project-specific (some reusable apps provide templates but those are usually intended as examples / starting points to be customized for your project's needs), and it's ok to use them (together with custom templatetags and context processoers) to bind features from different apps together.

But sometimes you need a bit more than just template-layer integration. What I use to do on most django projects is to have a "main" app acting as the "integration" layer - this app is allowed to depend on any other app, but no app is allowed to depend on it. This app will typically hosts the homepage, base templates, static assets etc.

FWIW I also usually have a "core" app provinding the core of the project's domain layer (models, business logic etc), which  everyone is allowed to depend upon but is not allowed to depend on any other app (except of course contrib apps like `auth` etc).

Note that (as already mentioned by Atcrank) there are really two kinds of django apps: reusable apps and project-specific ones. A reusable app must obviously have as few dependencies as possible (and of course none on your project-specific apps - seems obvious), but it also must provide as much "hooks" as possible for integration with your project's specific needs (via signals, custom templatetags, overridable templates, abstract base classes, mixins etc).

A project-specific app OTHO is, well, specific to your project, so it's ok if it depends on another app as long as you avoid circular dependencies - hence my sandwich-style "core-apps-main" pattern, which provides a place for things everyone else depends on and a place for things that depends on everyone else (and some place in-between for other features).

In your example, what you named "core" looks like it actually wants to be my own "main" layer and what you name "objects" would be either my "core" or some of the project-specific apps.

> One more question.. What about if in core/views.py call objects/views.py function which return list with objects (filtered or not) and pass this list to home.html (...)  Or create something like service, which operate with Objects model

This doesn't change much wrt/ dependencies - instead of depending on `objects.models`, your core app now depends on `objects.views` or on some "service"( whatever it's supposed to be), which itself depends on `objects.models`, so you're replacing a direct dependency by an indirect one - which is less obvious and can be a pain to debug (I once had a circular import issue spawning a dozen indirection levels thru  django signals, "clever" hacks, dynamic imports etc and I can tell you it was no fun to trace).

Now as I said, you WILL have to couple your apps one way or another to make them work together, and the two obvious places to do so are 1/ the template layer and 2/ a dedicated "main" app (you can call it whatever you want - I named it "main" because it's the canonical name for an application entry point -, the point here is that this app is allowed to depend on every other app but no other app should ever depend on it).

If you want to use templates as integration layers so for example the template for `appA.views.somemodel_index` can display informations from `appB.models` without `appA` knowing anything about it, the simple obvious solution is to add some custom templatetag in `appB` that will retrieve /format / render those informations and use this custom templatetag where needed in your templates.

But there's only so much you can do at the template layer and some features that needs to know about models/functions/whatever from different, supposedly unrelated apps will be better implemented in the view or model (signals etc) layers, hence the use of an "integration" app.

Comment: Hmm.. thank you. One more question.. What about if in `core/views.py` call `objects/views.py` function which return list with objects (filtered or not) and pass this list to `home.html` is it good solution (your opinion).

Comment: Or create something like service, which operate with Objects model

Comment: Bruno, I feel like this answer deserves to be in the Django documentation somewhere (maybe in the tutorial section about packaging and reusing.) Very clarifying.

Comment: @Atcrank thanks - and well, feel free to suggest this to the django team if you want.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Done! I hope they see it, I'll write if I get an answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is the sort of design question which is hard for other people to answer, and you've been here longer than me and I'm not sure I'm going to help you at all...

Anyway, the reason to make the split as you have is that you want to re-use 'core' for several apps with different objects in each app(?). Otherwise it would be easy enough to make it all happen in one app.

I have a few different apps, each with different models. I reuse a common header and footer. I think the right design for this is actually to build the apps interacting with the objects you want through urls dedicated to those apps, with the omnipresent 'core' functions and links handled in a context processor (a [context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors) is a function that returns context variables that will be available during rendering).

Comment: `the reason to make the split as you have is that you want to re-use 'core' for several apps` - Yes, but objects are same with different filters, for example it would looks like booking.com, where hotels are objects in my APP, I just want Objects APP to be completely separate. Home page - all objects with AJAX based filters, profile of users with there objects. and that's it. Thanks for your answer I would check the link.